# Suggestions for proposed SQL 2017 SSIS Scale-out layout along with some questions

Tags: sql-server-2017, ssis-2017

We're putting in a new SQL 2017 environment, and given we're heavily dependent on SSIS I would like to use the SSIS SCale-out feature.  We've generally setup pairs of SSIS servers for redundancy, so I'm excited to check out Scale out.  I have some questions though which I can't find answers to in any of the MS docs or elsewhere.

My proposed layout is this:

- SQL Server 1 - AG Replica 1
- SQL Server 2 - AG Replica 2
- Master SSIS Server (SSISDB on AG)
- Worker SSIS Server 1
- Worker SSIS Server 2

So with this my questions are:

- If the Master SSIS Server is down, will the Worker SSIS Servers still be able to execute jobs?
- Can I setup multiple Master SSIS Servers for redundancy?
- What is the recovery process if the environment needs to be rebuilt?
- If a job is set to run every 5 minutes and it starts executing on Worker 1 at 10:05pif it's not complete by 10:10pm will Worker 2 execute another instance of it?
- Would it be better to run Worker/Master on one server and Worker on another?  Reducing the number of servers?
- When deploying SSIS solutions are they deployed to Master which pushes them to the Workers or are they deployed to each Worker one at a time?
- Any other caveats to running in this layout?

My goal is two fold - performance and redundancy as SSIS has always been the one place we had no redundancy given it wasn't supported to run the SSISDB on an AG until now.

Thanks for any suggestions or feedback.